# How would I be able to read and render fonts in Java with a pixel array?

Tags: java, text, fonts, rendering

For fun and to lean about Java I've tasked myself with creating an application that can render images and lines with a pixel array.

I have a function that sets a pixel's colour in that array:
`pixel(int x, int y, int colour)`

How would I go about reading and storing the font data in pixels then rendering it to the screen pixel by pixel?  something like:
`drawText(String text, int colour, float size)`

Comment: Are you asking how to paint on a component with the java.awt.Graphics or are you asking how to make a font definition file to place in the operating system server.   Nb if you use a method from graphics object of the component you want to paint, to set something e.g. drawString(), call thecomponent.repaint() after.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the font to a pixel image?  Or just trying to render text using a specific font?  What toolkit are you using (AWT/Swing/JavaFX/something else) to render the graphics with?

Comment: I am using a Buffered Image along with `java.awt.image.DataBufferInt`; I only use the graphics component to render the pixel array.  I want to be able to read and store the tff font that is located in the project folder in pixel data, then replace the pixel data with the font's pixel data to then be rendered on the screen.

Comment: Wondering if the stream is useable this way, correct way is getResourceAsStream()  not FileInputStram     byte[] pxf = new byte[ttffilelength]; Font pixfont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT , new FileInputStream(filenamepathttf).read(pxf,0, ttffilelength)) Qvicky... read in all the file bytes in one long call (use getResourceAsStream not this)